# Issue calling module to read lines from a file using Python 3

Tags: python, file, readline

I want to have a loop in my main .py that calls a module that will open a file and return a line from the file, then I want to perform logic on said line in the main code, then ask the module for the next line.  At this point my code returns the same line over and over until EOF and I'm not sure how to fix.

Main Code:

```
fwname = input('Please enter the file name (case sensitive): ')

readline = HexFileParser.ParseHex(fwname)

for line in readline:
    #perform some logic   
    print (readline)
```

Module (HexFileParser):

```
def ParseHex(filelocation):

    fwfile = open("C:\\Path\\"+filelocation,'r')
    line = fwfile.readline()
    endstring = ":00000001FF"

    for line in fwfile:
        if line.find(endstring) == -1:
            return line.lstrip(':')  
        else:
            break
```

Thank you!

Comment: As a side note, `if endstring not in line` is a simpler (and possibly even faster, sometimes) way to do `if line.find(endstring) == -1`. Don't use `find` unless you need to know the position.

Comment: Hexparser is supposed to open a file and return each line so that I can encode the hex line to binary in my main code.  I like it being a separate file that I can call because eventually I will have multiple different firmware files I want to parse and send back to the main code to be translated into binary.  I will change the code to I am not using find anymore, thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is a [generator function](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators).*

As written, your `ParseHex` function will `return` the first line that doesn't contain `endstring`. After that, it's done, and won't do anything else (unless you call it again).

But if you change that `return` to a `yield`, the function returns a generator. And, when you iterate over that generator, you'll get all of the values it `yield`s until it's finished.

With a simpler example:

```
>>> def spam():
...     for i in range(10):
...         return '{} servings of spam'.format(i)
```

This returns a single string, `"0 servings of spam"`. Because strings happen to be iterable (you get the individual characters), the following code will print out `0` on one line, a space on the next, an `s` on the next, and so on.

```
>>> for i in spam():
...     print(i)
```

But with one little change:

```
>>> def spam():
...     for i in range(10):
...         yield '{} servings of spam'.format(i)
```

Now this returns an iterator over 10 strings. So, running the following code will print `0 servings of spam`, `1 servings of spam`, and so on.

```
>>> for i in spam():
...     print(i)
```

---

There's more information on generators [on the wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), and [David Beazley's presentations](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/) on generators are definitely worth reading.

---

* If I've guessed right, kudos on coming up with the idea on your own. Seriously, most people don't realize how useful generators are until exposed to numerous examples; you figured out they'd be useful and just got stuck trying to figure out what they're called and how they're written in Python.

Comment: Ok that makes sense!  So what I can do it find the total lines in the file, -1 because I never want to send to last line, and then yield each line.  THANK YOU!  I'm a super noob and have been thrown into a situation where I am coding beyond my ability but this site has been so helpful.

Comment: I can't even upvote you because I have too little rep, but thank you.

Comment: @ThorPeterson: I believe you can [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), which is more important than upvoting anyway. (It lets everyone who searches later know that this was a good question that has a useful answer.)